# Connecting an interior and boundary point of an open, connected subset of the unit circle using a path.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, curves

Let $B:=\{w\in \mathbb{R}^2 : \lvert w\rvert < 1\}$ be the unit circle. Suppose that $Q$ is an open, connected subset of $B$, such that a boundary point $q\in \partial Q$ lies in $\partial B$. For an arbitrary interior point $x\in Q$, I want to find a path $\Gamma$ which connects $x$ and $q$ such that $\Gamma$ lies in $Q$ (except for $q$). I may also use the boundary points of $Q$ which lie in $B$, namely $\partial Q \cap B$, in order to construct such a path.

Comment: No, such construction need not even be continuous at $1$. Pieces connecting $y_n$ to $y_{n+1}$ may create some other limit points at $1$, for example when middle points of each curve converge somewhere else than $y$.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if the result is true or not? A proof would be nice, but that is the only thing which is important for me to know.

Comment: No, the statement is false. Think of constructing an example using topologist's sine curve.

Comment: Without some regularity condition on $\partial B$ the claim is false. This is basically because the closure of any connected set is (connected, but) not necessarily path connected. Thus, starting from your favourite example of connected, non path-connected space, you can build a counterexample where an connected open set $B$ has a boundary point not reachable with paths from inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your construction unfortunately need not be continuous at $1$. That's because middle points of each curve may converge to somewhere else than $y$, breaking the continuity.

Moreover, there is no way to fix that: the statement is not true in general. Consider

$$U_n=(1/n-\epsilon_n, 1/n+\epsilon_n)\times\mathbb{R}$$

Here I choose $\epsilon_n$ to be small enough so that $U_n\cap U_m=\emptyset$ for $n\neq m$. Something like $\epsilon_n=1/n^2$.

Then we define $B=\mathbb{R}\times(-1,1)\cup\big(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty U_n\big)$. So these are infinitely many vertical thick lines ("convergent" to the $Y$-axis) together with a single horizontal thick line. Our $B$ is clearly connected and open. But for example $(0,2)\in\partial B$ and there is no path (Jordan or not) almost entirely contained in $B$ with $(0,2)$ as its endpoint.

Also note that the example above can be made bounded by intersecting everything with any big enough (i.e. of radius $>1$) ball around $(0,0)$.

Comment: Thank you. However, the book that I'm reading uses the fact that we can construct such a path: Let $B:= \{w\in \mathbb{R}^2 : \lvert w\rvert <1\}$ be the unit-circle. Suppose that $Q\subset B$ is open and connected, such that a boundary point $q\in \partial Q$ lies on $\partial B$. We can construct a path from an interior point of $Q$ to $q$ which lies completly in $Q$ (except for $q$). Did I make a mistake in generalizing this problem as described in my question (apart from the fact that $\Gamma$ had to be a jordan curve) or is this simply not true?

Comment: @Mandelbrot that satement is false. The example I've provided can be easily tweaked to falsify it. So either you've missed some assumption or there's a mistake in the book. What book is that? And where the statement is?

Comment: The book is "Minimal Surfaces" by Hildebrandt, Dierkes and Sauvigny.  It's a minor result in the proof of Lemma 2 (Rado's Lemma) on page 296.

"Moreover, for any of these $w_j$ we can construct a path $\gamma_j$ in
$Q_j$ starting in the sector $\sigma_j$ and ending at $w_j$".

Comment: However I do believe the proof still works with slight modifications. By reason which follow from the proof, we can also use the boundary points of $Q$ which lie in $B$, namely $\partial Q \cap B$, for the construction of our path. Would the result then be true?

Comment: @Mandelbrot I've checked the book. It is a bit difficult for me to follow the proof (I am not an expert in complex analysis), but I think this piece of the proof is crucial: "Consequently the set (...) divides a neighborhood of $w_0$ into $2n$ open sectors (...) **by means of $2n$ analytic arcs emanating from $w_0$**". I'm not sure why this is the case, but those open subsets are of very specific shape. Only that implies the existance of the curve. Anyway these open subsets are open components of nonzeros of a harmonic function. And I think that is important. But I can't help you with that.

Comment: First of all, I am really thankful for the effort you have put into my question. However, as I understand it, we can only guarantee the existence/smoothness of these arcs in a close neighbourhood of $w_0$. As stated, we obtain sectors $\sigma_1,..., \sigma_{2n}$. Now we choose connected components $Q_1,..., Q_{2n}$ of $\{w\in B:f(w)\neq 0\}$ such that $\sigma_i$ is contained in $Q_i$. I don't think we can draw any conclusions about the boundary of the components $Q_i$, but I am not entirely sure either.